# Convert JPG,PNG etc formats to PGM and make an array: Python

Tags: python-3.x, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am converting .pgm images to array using below function. But right now i got all formats of images like .jpg/png etc. now i want to convert everything to .pgm (without savings) and needs to convert to array. i am using below function to convert into arrays

```
def image_array(pgm):
    pic = image.load_img(pgm, target_size=(224, 224))
    x = image.img_to_array(pic)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)
    npfeatures = np.array(x)
    return npfeatures
```

I tried below methods but couldnt integrate these things to above function.

```
image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/N/Desktop/Test.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

imports i used

- from keras.preprocessing import image
- from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
- import cv2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give the same result as your `image_array` function:

```
def image_array(filename):
    x = cv2.imread(filename)
    x = cv2.resize(x, (224, 224))
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)
    npfeatures = np.array(x)
    return npfeatures
```

Now if you want to have a one-channel image, i.e (224, 224) instead of (224, 224, 3), just use `cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`.

And if you want it to be (224, 224, 3), but appearing grey, i.e. having all 3 color components equal, use

```
    x = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    x = cv2.resize(x, (224, 224))
    x = np.tile(np.expand_dims(x, 2), 3)
```

Comment: My function gives me (224,224,3) for all type of files files. i am expecting converted images to be (224,224,3) not (224,224) because my model accepts (224,224,3)

Comment: So leave it without `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`

Comment: @Ashu I added one more tip, may be this is what you need. Actually it is not clear what you need, because PGM is a file format for saving images on disk. But you don't want to save an image on disk, you need some color conversion, but I can't understand which one.